# Marker is not pointing on the map

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

The data is fetched in the correct format but the marker is not loading, please let me figure out this issue

```js
function initMap() {
        // Create the map.
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(); 
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapView'), {
          zoom: 5,
          center: {lat: 20.5937, lng: 78.9629}, 
          mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
        });
   $.getJSON('data.php', function(data){
    // alert(data);
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
            var marker = [];
            var infowindow = [];
            var contentString = [];
            for(var sd in data){
                contentString[sd] = '<div id="content">'+
                    '<div id="siteNotice">'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">'+data[sd].hqname+'</h1>'+
                    '<div id="bodyContent">'+
                        '<p><b>Division: </b>'+data[sd].division+'</p>'+
                        '<p><b>From: </b>'+data[sd].fromareaname+'</p>'+
                        '<p><b>To: </b>'+data[sd].toareaname+'</p>'+
                        '<p><b>Category: </b>'+data[sd].ta+'</p>'+
                        '<p><b>Distance: </b>'+data[sd].dist+'</p>'+
                        '<p><b>Calculated Distance: </b>'+data[sd].distance+'</p>'+
                    '</div>'+
                '</div>';
                
                infowindow[sd] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                  content: contentString[sd]
                });
    if(data[sd].type == 1){
                    marker[sd] = new google.maps.Marker({
                        icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png',
                        position: data[sd].center,
      map: map,
                        infowindow: infowindow[sd]
                    });
                }
                if(data[sd].type == 2){
                    marker[sd] = new google.maps.Marker({
                        icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png',
                        position: data[sd].center,
                        map: map,
                        infowindow: infowindow[sd]
                    });
                }
               
            }
        });

      
   
}
```

Json Data:

> "0": {        "division": "ARV",      "hqname": "HYDERABAD",      "fromareaname":
>   "HYDERABAD",      "toareaname": "VANASTHALIPURAM",        "ta": "EXHQ",
>         "center": {             "latitude": "17.328644",            "longitude": "78.575301"
>         },      "type": "1",        "dist": "36",       "distance": "11"    }

Comment: I think your json is not valid. Make the json format proper.

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle?

Comment: json is valid i have checked

Comment: i dont know the fiddle creation @Lajos Arpad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your marker **position** property. You're not defining the **lat/lng** the correct way. It has to be a **number** (which is string in your data sample). And it has to be in `{lat : <number>, lng : <number> }` format.

Try updating like this

```
marker[sd] = new google.maps.Marker({
                        icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png',
                        position: {lat : parseFloat(data[sd].center.latitude), lng : parseFloat(data[sd].center.longitude)},
                        map: map,
                        infowindow: infowindow[sd]
                    });
```

As you can see, I use parseFloat to cast your string values to a float number.

Check in jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5u16yy7h/1/

Comment: sorry, add an event to marker  (https://jsfiddle.net/5u16yy7h/2/)

`marker[sd].addListener('click', function() {
    infowindow[sd].open(map, marker[sd]);`